# Парсинг fb2 файла

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

В fb2 файле есть блоки

```
<section>
    <title>
        <p>Глава 1</p>
    </title>

    текст 

    <section>
        <title>
            <p>Подглава 1</p>
        </title>

        текст

    </section>
    <section>
        <title>
            <p>Подглава 2</p>
        </title>

        текст

    </section>
</section>

<section>
    <title>
        <p>Глава 2</p>
    </title>

    текст 

    <section>
        <title>
            <p>Подглава 1</p>
        </title>

        текст

    </section>
    <section>
        <title>
            <p>Подглава 2</p>
        </title>

        текст

    </section>
</section>
```

section могут быть вложенными. Как пройтись по документу, выбрать все названия глав и составить древовидную структуру для вывода в TreeView?

глава 1
--подглава 1
--подглава 2
глава 2
--подглава 1
--подглава 2
глава 3
глава 4

Comment: Это xml. Используйте любой xml-парсер.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я понимаю про парсер, но как собрать древов-ю структуру не пойму, как сделать рекурсию, или как то по другому?

Comment: загружаете в `XDocument` и рекурсивно обходите в глубину по интересующим вас элементам. Там уже древовидная структура

Comment: Treeview - это что: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov wpf

Comment: Начните с создания модели (вью-модели), которую вам удобно было бы привязать к treeView, а потом уже думайте как эту модель заполнить из xml. Пока вопрос слишком общий и его можно разбить на два вышеупомянутых.